# SMS Receiving app crashes when new text message comes in - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor, smsmanager

I built an SMS send/receive activity and it all works fine. The receive part simply loads all my texts from my Android messaging app, into a `ListView`. This works too. The problem is when a new text message comes in, it crashes immediately. Even if I am in another application or on the home screen, I get a pop up that says my app crashed, and keeps re-crashing every time a new message comes in. Why is it crashing and how do I fix it? The `ListView` that contains the messages should update when a new message comes in. I patch-worked this code together, so it's likely I'm missing something. Also, just focus on the `SMSReceiver` class (in `SMSListFragment.java`) and `refreshSmsInbox()` (in `SMSMain.java`), as those places are where the loading into my ListView happens. Also, `updateList()` updates this whole process, but only if there are pre-existing messages in my inbox. It would be nice if the update could actually update in real time. Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

In my Manifest, here are my related permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"
          android:exported="true"> 
      <intent-filter android:priority="999"> 
          <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
      </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

**SMSMain.java**

```
package org.azurespot.practiceapp.sms;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.azurespot.practiceapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SMSMain extends Activity {

    protected EditText etPhoneNumber;
    protected static EditText etMessage;
    protected View dialogView;
    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;
    private static SMSMain smsMain;
    ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView smsListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    public static SMSMain instance() {
        return smsMain;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        smsMain = this;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smsmain);

        // initialize ListView for displaying SMS messages
        smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
        smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        // long click on ListView item will delete message
        smsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long arg3) {

                //removes item at position you long-click on
                smsMessagesList.remove(pos);//where arg2 is position of item you click
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  

                 return true;
            }
        });


    } // end onCreate


    public void readSMS(View v){

        refreshSmsInbox();
    }

    // adds text messages to the ListView via the adapter
    public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse
                    ("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            String str = "SMS From: " + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                    "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
            arrayAdapter.add(str);
        } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
        arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void composeSMS(View v){

        // build your dialog box
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SMSMain.this);
        // Get the layout inflater & inflate the box
        final LayoutInflater inflater = SMSMain.this.getLayoutInflater();
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_compose_sms, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
     // get phone number and message IDs
        etPhoneNumber = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sms_phone);
        etMessage = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sms_message);
        builder.setTitle("Send an SMS");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                // Turns the entered phone number and message into String
                String phoneNumber = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                String message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim(); 
                // error check to make sure there is input
                if (phoneNumber.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0) 
                    // sends the SMS
                    sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);                
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter a phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        // put all your builders in one create command
        dialog = builder.create(); 
        // show the dialog box
        dialog.show();

    }

    // clicked the microphone button to start speech to text
    public void speechToText(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(
                            RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
            etMessage.setText("");
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Ooopps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }

    }

    // method for sending the SMS
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {        
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                    new Intent(this, SMSMain.class), 0);                
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
        }   

    public void addContact(View v) {

        // add a contact. using Android's ContactPicker
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_SPEECH){
            // speech to text result
            switch (requestCode) {
                case RESULT_SPEECH: {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                        ArrayList<String> text = data
                                .getStringArrayListExtra
                                (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                        etMessage.setText(text.get(0));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        } // end if

        // picks a contact, puts into EditText
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                Cursor cursor = null;
                String phone = "";
                try{
                    Uri result = data.getData();
                    // get the contact id from the URI
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                    // query for phone number
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);

                    int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        phone = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                    } 
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Getting contact failed.");
                 } finally {

                    etPhoneNumber.setText(phone, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                    if (phone.length() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No phone number found for contact.",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                     if (cursor != null){
                            cursor.close();
                     }

                 } // end finally
                 break;  
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

**SMSListFragment.java**

```
package org.azurespot.practiceapp.sms;

import org.azurespot.practiceapp.R;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSListFragment extends ListFragment{

    public static View viewList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      // Defines the XML file for the fragment
      viewList = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_messages_fragment, 
                                                        container, false);

      return viewList;
    }

    public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //---get the SMS message passed in---
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            SmsMessage[] messages = null;
            String msgString = ""; 

            if (bundle != null)
            {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                    msgString += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                    msgString += " :";
                    msgString += messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    msgString += "\n"; 



                }

                //---display the new SMS message---
                SMSMain smsMain = SMSMain.instance();
                smsMain.updateList(msgString);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141): Process: org.azurespot.practiceapp, PID: 13141
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver org.azurespot.practiceapp.SMSReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.azurespot.practiceapp.SMSReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.azurespot.practiceapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.azurespot.practiceapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2608)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:173)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.azurespot.practiceapp.SMSReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.azurespot.practiceapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.azurespot.practiceapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2603)
01-01 18:24:09.444: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"
      android:exported="true"> 
  <intent-filter android:priority="999"> 
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

the `.` in `android:name=".SMSReceiver"` will be expanded to your package name. What you wrote in the manifest is therefore equivalent to

```
<receiver android:name="org.azurespot.practiceapp.SMSReceiver"
      android:exported="true"> 
  <intent-filter android:priority="999"> 
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Note that this path does not match that of the class `SMSReceiver` you define inside your `SMSListFragment`, which is what the logcat error indicates.

You should probably be using `android:name=".sms.SMSListFragment.SMSReceiver"` in the manifest instead. The `SMSReceiver` nested class may also need to be declared static to be accessed in this way.

Comment: Thanks stkent, I had no idea that was needed. Although I made that change, and it is still giving me that error, with the new name. I did make `SMSReceiver` static too. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver org.azurespot.practiceapp.sms.SMSListFragment.SMSReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.azurespot.practiceapp.sms.SMSListFragment.SMSReceiver" ...`

Comment: Well that's weird, because `org.azurespot.practiceapp.sms.SMSListFragment.SMSReceiver` looks like the correct path now. Your `SMSListFragment` is still in the `sms` package, right?

Comment: On second thought, my refresh code is in `SMSMain`... although the list does refresh just fine, but it's just that real-time refreshing that it can't handle, then it crashes. I don't know if those are connected, but `SMSMain` is not in the manifest, although it's not a receiver, so maybe it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Yeah, the `SMSListFragment.java` is in the `.sms` package. :/

Comment: `SMSMain` should be declared as an Activity in the manifest. The logcat still shows a ClassNotFoundException though, so the problem probably lies with `SMSReceiver`. No other ideas off the top of my head I'm afraid.

Comment: You know, I think it might have something to do with the `refreshSmsInbox()` being confined in a button. So it works when I first press the button, which is `Read SMS`, but then when a text comes in, there is no way for the handler to receive it, since it only runs in the button. Do you think that could be it? Not sure where else to put it since I got the code from somewhere else. They just put it in their main activity, not a button. Maybe I should try `onCreate` in the activity?

Comment: Based on the reported Exception, I still think it's more likely that the manifest declaration/path are somehow screwy. I'll leave the answer up for now as reference for others.

Comment: It's odd because all the code in the receiver class works fine, and queries my inbox and shows the text messages in a list like it should, so the system finds the receiver okay then. Only when that signal from the `SMS_RECEIVED` comes in, is the class lost somehow. But no idea why.

Comment: I ended up registering my receiver programmatically in `onResume()` and `onPause()` of `SMSMain`, and while it does not update automatically (I have to press the button `Read SMS` again), it will update to the latest text message and post it into my `ListView`. So I'm thinking, this is good enough for me! ;) No more error at least. Thanks for your help. :)